# JPA and order of columns in the database

Tags: jpa, jakarta-ee

I'm using Eclipselink as my persistence provider. Is there any way to specify the order in which the columns appear in the database? The column-order in the database doesn't match the attribute-order in my entities. As far as I've understood hibernate order columns alphabetically but I can't find any specifications for Eclipselink.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EclipseLink sorts the mappings and thus their columns based on the weight of the mapping.  Normally the weight is not set other than to ensure that Baisc mappings are first, and relationship mappings are second.

You can set the weight for a mapping if you desire using a DescriptorCustomizer.  You could also set the descriptor to not order mapping by weight, so the order that they were specified will be used (setShouldOrderMappings(false)).

```
public void MyCustomizer implements DescriptorCustomizer {
  public void customize(ClassDescriptor descriptor) {
    descriptor.getMappingForAttributeName("name").setWeight(2);
  }
}
```

There have been some recent changes to the weighting of mappings in the 2.2 development, the mappings are now sorted by name within the same weight levels.

Comment: Correct answer but not sure `setShouldOrderMappings(false)` does what you expect. There's, AFAIK, no way to get the order as specified in the source code file which is in fact typically what you want. So you'll need to specify the weights explicitly as in your code example.

Comment: See [this blog](http://marsparanoma.blogspot.dk/2014/01/how-to-set-column-order-in-jpa-under.html) for a full example of how to do this using custom annotations.

Comment: Columns that are part of a composite PK cannot have their order set using the 'setWeight' method as described here. Instead you must the EclipseLink `@PrimaryKey` annotation for such columns (you'll be interested in controlling the order of the columns in the PK index, not just how those columns are listed in the table itself). For all other columns the method described here will work fine. Tested on EclipseLink 2.6.